# Stop iframe auto play after modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a modal window with an iframe that plays everytime the modal is oppened. This was archived by adding "?autoplay=1" to see the src path of the iframe, using jquery. How can I take out the same "?autoplay=1" from the iframe using jquery?

```
$('#m1 .trigger').click(function() {
 $("#m1 .modal").fadeIn(500);
 var symbol = $("#mvf1")[0].src.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?";
 $("#mvf1")[0].src += symbol + "autoplay=1";
});
```

Comment: then pass different value or omit the params?

Comment: `$("#mvf1")[0].src = ""`

Answer (score 0):

I think I over complicated things before, so I just rewrote my code using some good attr function to pass the video url with the autoplay atribute, and just removed that src when the modal is closed, so there is no danger of the video continue being played.

```
//open modal and autoplay video
$('#m1 .trigger').click(function() {
　$("#m1 .modal").fadeIn(500);
　$("#m1 .youtube-video").attr("src","https://www.youtube.com/embed/MeWQjqU?autoplay=1");
});

//close modal and stop video
$('#m1 .modal').click(function() {
　$(this).fadeOut(500);
　$("#m1 .youtube-video").removeAttr('src');
});
```